# Windows 8 MDM - Company Apps

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, mdm

While going through the article at "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/04/19/managing-quot-byo-quot-pcs-in-the-enterprise-including-woa.aspx", I came across the statement "The agent then performs a service lookup to locate the organization’s management infrastructure based on the user’s email address."

I understand that this is how the Company App connect to the organization's network. The questions are:

1. What is this service? Is this something that will be developed and hosted by the organization?
2. If yes, then how will be Company App will connect to this specific service URL for enrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows RT devices can be managed with [Windows Intune](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windowsintune/pc-management.aspx) and [Microsoft System Center 2012 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/configuration-manager-2012.aspx). Intune is a cloud-based service from Microsoft (11$ per month and user) whereas SCCM is self-hosted in the network of your company.

Because there is no information about the protocol used by Microsoft currently, it's hard to tell whether a custom implementation will be possible in the future. It's likely that they use a similiar protocol as used by the [Windows Phone 8 MDM agent](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/C/4/5C460CE2-3B0F-45CE-805D-1A3D5697639C/WP8_Enterprise_Device_Management_Protocol.pdf) ([OMA DM XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_Device_Management)).

Have a look at [this article](http://mobilitydojo.net/2012/12/20/windows-rt-mdm-first-impressions/) to get an idea how you can manage your Windows RT devices with Windows Intune.

Comment: there is term discovery service in the above attached document what does it mean by Discovery service and also help me out to find what i need to have in server for all the enrollment process.